# Why are getters of public state variables not recognised by interfaces?

Tags: solidity

In code like the below, `address public balance` has an automatic getter function (as can be seen in the corresponding ABI).

However we need to redefine it to avoid the compiler complaining that Test does not fully implement ITest.

Any idea if this is a bug or a feature (and if so why)?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

interface ITest {
    function balance() external returns (address);
}

contract Test is ITest {
    address public balance;

    // Why is this function needed?
    function balance() public returns (address) {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is considered a bug in the Solidity compiler, but I haven't seen anyone say when/if it will be fixed.

Answer (score -2):

As of the [official docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#abstract-contracts) of the `0.4.24` compiler version :

any contract with a function without an implementation, is an abstract contract automatically. If you inherit from an abstract contract, you will have to implement all functions that are not implemented in the parent contract.

Interfaces are exactly the same, only that you need to implement all functions defined in the interface ( since it doesn't implement any function at all ), thus the necessity of implementing the `Balance()`.

for the state variable `Balance` It would be better if you changed the name and tested the outcome, it may be just a name collusion ( even if that looks not easy to happen ).

Comment: I think the point is that `address public balance` _does_ implement the interface `function balance() external returns (address);`, but the compiler doesn't seem to understand that.

Comment: Yep - exactly. State variables which are public get automatic getter functions (which appear in the contracts ABI) - trying to understand if there is a good reason these are not recognised as matching the interface (vs. a bug / slightly broken implementation).

Comment: I am still pretty sure it is just a naming collision, where a `Balance` function is mandatory from the interface inheritance. It just happens to have the same name as a state variable balance. In case this is true, it should be noted in a warning by the compiler.